# A number of teams playing against each other: what is a fitting game term?

Tags: game-design, terminology, tournament

Basically I am looking for the right expression for a specific set (usually 2-6) of teams (a team is a group of individuals controlled by one player) in a tounament-like game. The team-set is a subset of a larger number of existing teams e.g.: there exist 10 teams t1, ..., t10. Team-Set 1 is {t1, t3, t7}, team-Set 2 is {t1, t5, t8, t10} and so on. What would be a good expression for "team-set" in a somewhat-military (fun-based combat) game context?

The teams of the set fight against each other, and not together (alongside each other). So I am looking for a somewhat confrontative term.

Comment: Are you asking for a *definition* of "a subset of teams from a larger set entered in a tournament?" Or are you asking for a word that *sounds cool* to use for that concept in your own game? One of those things is opinion-based, but the other isn't (although it may be off-topic).

Answer (score 1):

How about battalion? I think it fits what you are wanting.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the teams of the set fight against each other, and not together.

Comment: Oh, in that case, my answer is completely off. I'll update it if I come up with anything that does fit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some of the terms from Wikipedia's [Military Organization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_organization#Modern_hierarchy) page, for example:

- Formation
- Regiment
- Division